# How can I create a round bottle shape?

Tags: modeling, bevel, boolean-modifier

So I'm trying to make a 3D model of this bottle, which has lots of different shapes and dents, and I can't seem to do it without having a really messy mesh.

I was wondering if anyone has any tips on how I can simplify the process.

I started from a square that I loop cut and moved to fit the shape, and then tried beveling and smoothing it on all sides.

Any advice would be very helpful, thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin by drawing the main shapes, mirror on X:

[image]

Extrude:

[image]

Pull the edges to create the 3D reliefs, mirror on Y:

[image]

Comment: very nice method! +1

Comment: thanks a lot! @Harry McKenzie